# icons and splash screens not copied from phonegap to android platform

Tags: android, cordova

I created custom icons and splash screens for my phonegap android application.  I created the phonegap application by using 'phonegap create' and I replaced all the stock icons and splash screens with custom made icons and splash screens.

Below is my folder structure of the images and splash after executing 'phonegap create' command

```
-myproject
--www
---icon.png
---res
----icon
-----android
------icon-36-ldpi.png
------icon-48-mdpi.png
------icon-72-hdpi.png
------icon-96-xhdpi.png
----screen
-----android
------screen-hdpi-landscape.png
------screen-hdpi-portrait.png
------screen-ldpi-landscape.png
------screen-ldpi-portrait.png
------screen-mdpi-landscape.png
------screen-mdpi-portrait.png
------screen-xhdpi-landscape.png
------screen-xhdpi-portrait.png
```

Below is the config.xml

```
<icon src="www/icon.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
```

Now I execute the 'phonegap build android' I dont see all the icons and splash screens are not copied to platforms\android\res folder.  I only see the stock phonegap icons and splash screens.

I dont want to manually copy the icons and splash screens for each platform.  It should happen automatically while building the phonegap for a target platoform.  How should I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after moving the config.xml inside www folder and removed all www/ references in config.xml.

I.e,. the image paths should be relative where the config.xml exists.

Answer (score 0):

Other way (works for me) using `gap:density="ldpi"` without moving any file

```
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" gap:density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" gap:density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" gap:density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" gap:density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
```